# How to check if a point belongs to a segment in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: geometry

I have a very simple question. Consider the segment $x$ given by $\{(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}),(1,0,0)\}$. Then, my question is: does the point $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},0)$ belong to such a segment $x$? Regardless of what the answer is (either yes or no), can you please show how to solve this question in general terms (as framed in the title)? Thank you all in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Indicating with $P=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}) \quad Q=(1,0,0)$

- write the parametric equation for the segment $P+t(Q-P)$
- equate to the coordinates $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},0)$
  and verify whether a solution exists for $t\in[0,1]$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I appreciate your hint, and following what you suggest, the answer I found is no. Could you please verify it just to make sure I didn't do it wrong?

Comment: @Hector Yes of course indeed we have $$P+t(P-Q)=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}) +t(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3})=(\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},0)$$ which has not solution.

Comment: As soon as I can, I will accept your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hector You are welcome! Bye